# How to use rewrite rule to replace tabs with spaces in gofmt tool?

Tags: go, gofmt

`gofmt` command supports -r flag to use rewrite rule during formatting the code. How to use it to replace *tabs indentation* with the *spaces indentation*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> [Command gofmt](https://golang.org/cmd/gofmt/)
>
> The rewrite rule specified with the -r flag must be a string of the
>   form:
>
> ```
> pattern -> replacement
> ```
>
> Both pattern and replacement must be valid Go expressions.

The tab and space characters are not valid Go expressions. It won't work.

> The Go Programming Language
>
> Alan A. A. Donovan & Brian W. Kernighan
>
> ISBN: 978-0134190440
>
> [gopl.io](http://www.gopl.io/)
>
> Go takes a strong stance on code formatting. The gofmt tool rewrites
>   code into the standard format, and the go tool’s fmt subcommand
>   applies gofmt to all the files in the specified package, or the ones
>   in the current directory by default. All Go source files in the book
>   have been run through gofmt, and you should get into the habit of
>   doing the same for your own code. Declaring a standard format by fiat
>   eliminates a lot of pointless debate about trivia and, more
>   importantly, enables a variety of automated source code
>   transformations that would be infeasible if arbitrary formatting were
>   allowed.

Always use gofmt code formatting.

Comment: Coders can, and do, choose different tab widths in their editor. So, by picking tabs as the standard, Go in fact enforced inconsistent programmer experience :(  Also, the last quoted rationale means that , no matter  what formal syntax rules are, Go has in fact meaningful indentation just like Python. It's fine to make a decision and stick with it, but we should be honest about the effects.

Answer (score 5):

Go's format forced by `gofmt` dictates to use tab indentation.
Also see the decision lead to it:
 https://code.google.com/p/go/issues/detail?id=7101